# Inaccessible password field after screen lock, then boot error

Tags: boot, login, snap, gdm

I've just installed Ubuntu 23.10 on a new machine. When I return after a break, I find that the screen is locked and I need to enter my password. Once today and once yesterday I have found the field to enter my password inaccessible; and so I am unable to login. A restart of the machine, does not even boot to the GUI. The second time I encountered this, there was also a "Snapd User Session Agent" panel, and another panel with a green arrow, at the bottom of the lock/login GUI (neither respond; screenshot is at the bottom). I explain how I was able to circumvent this below. My workaround is however not permanent; so it will likely hit me again. Can anyone advise? I am happy to remove snap components.

As I mentioned, restarting the machine leads to a screen of log messages concluding with the garbled:

```
Started gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager.ntil boot process finishes up...r Service.......tion, revision 83.
```

A prior message indicates that it may relate to the "revision 83" part above: `snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-83.mount`.

To work around this issue (each time):

1. Open tty3 by CTRL+ALT+F3; and log in
2. Uninstall the Gnome Display Manager (`sudo apt-get remove gdm3`)
3. Re-install the Gnome Display Manager (`sudo apt-get install gdm3`)
4. Reboot: `sudo reboot`.
5. Login as usual. It seems `nautilus` has disappeared, so (`sudo apt-get install nautilus`)

[image: the bottom of my lock/login screen]

Comment: The snapd User Session Agent is a service running always in the background. This message always appears on the lock screen. Thus, your problem is very likely not related to that. Did you check the logs of GDM whether you can find anything there? What you also could try is to run Ubuntu in a X-Server session instead of a Wayland session.

Comment: Thanks. I guess `journalctl -u gdm -b` could be useful. I expect that is derived from`/var/log/syslog`. For now, I see `Gdm: GdmSession: no session desktop files installed, aborting...` and `gdm.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=5/TRAP`, and `gdm.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'`. But I guess I have two problems (lock screen, and reboot), and I'm not sure which of these the messages relate to. I will look again at such logs after noting the time that it happens more accurately, if it happens again.

Comment: Based on similar bug reports, please try to run from a terminal: `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-session`
This hopefully will resolve the problem.

Comment: finally, have you solved the problem? I have the same issue

Comment: I don't have the problem any more, but I can't remember what fixed it. I would at least have tried noisefloor's suggestion regarding `ubuntu-session`.